# Is it ok to use Post.first instead of assigns(:post) in a controller test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, functional-testing

In a rails (4.2.x) app, in controller tests, I see a lot of examples where they use `assigns(:post)`, where I could use `Post.first` or `Post.find_by(title: 'foo')` instead. I don't understand the need for `assigns` at all. (I heard that assigns will be deprecated in rails 5, but until then, is it ok to use the object directly?) Is it wrong to do this, for example:

```
assert_redirected_to(post_path(Post.first))
```

instead of:

```
assert_redirected_to(post_path(assigns(:post))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assigns(:post)` is just a refer to an action variable `@post`.
Action can look like:

```
@post = Post.first
```

or:

```
@post = Post.find_by(title: 'foo')
```

In test through `assigns(:post)` you can get a `@post` variable from the controller action.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a scenario where I *have to* use `assigns(:post)` and cannot use `Post.first`, etc.?

Comment: If you want check case like: _is my action assigns a variable `post`_, You should use `assigns()` method. Something like `assert(assigns(:post))`

Answer (score 1):

Using `Post.first` is possible, but couples your test to the database implementation. You're testing controller functionality, so you can stub out the call to the db and speed up your test.

Stubbing out this call will look something like:

`before { allow(Post).to_receive(:find){ build :post } }`

In this case, your controller specs will continue to work if you check `assigns(:post)`, but they will break if you check `Post.first`